# UIAddressBook in UITableView with NSObjectClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, addressbook, abaddressbook

I need to make a `UITableView` which fetches address book contents in it and also a `UISearchBar` which searches the address book contents.

I need an implementation like this project

http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

But the problem is here the data is static and I want to load address book's data in it.

Comment: Are you asking for the code to access the address book and populate a UITableView?

Comment: here you are http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/retrieving-contacts-from-the-address-book

Comment: I need to implement this by taking a nsobject class because i need a searchbar too . I just need implementation like in link i gave above. @woodstock

Comment: Made it more legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created ContactData NSObject Class. In following method, I am creating its object for each contact. At the end, you will get NSMutableArray named contactArr.

-(void)loadContacts{

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBookRef = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
        //NSLog(@"%@", addressBook);
    });
}
else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {

    CFErrorRef *error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, error);
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex numberOfPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPeople; i++) {

        ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );

        NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));

        ContactData *dataObj = [[ContactData alloc]init];
        NSString *Name = @" ";

        if ([firstName length]>0) {

            if ([lastName length]>0) {

                Name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",firstName,lastName];
            }
            else{
                Name = firstName;
            }
        }
        else{
            Name = @" ";
        }

        ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
        //NSLog(@"\n%@\n", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);

        NSString *phoneNumber = @" ";

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {
            phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);
        }

        ABMultiValueRef Emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

        NSString *Email; //= @" ";

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(Emails); i++) {
            Email = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(Emails, i);

        }

        ABMultiValueRef Addresses = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);

        NSString *address = @" ";
        NSMutableDictionary* addressDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(Addresses); i++) {
            addressDict = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableDictionary *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(Addresses, i);

            //NSLog(@"address = %@", addressDict);

            NSString * street = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Street"];
            NSString * city = [addressDict objectForKey:@"City"];
            NSString * state = [addressDict objectForKey:@"State"];
            NSString *country = [addressDict objectForKey:@"Country"];


            if (country.length>0 || state.length>0 || city.length>0 || street.length>0) {

                if (country.length>0 && state.length>0) {

                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", state,country];
                }
                else if(country.length>0 && city.length>0){
                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", city,country];
                }
                else if (state.length>0 && street.length>0){
                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", street,country];
                }
                else if (state.length>0 && city.length>0){
                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", city,state];
                }
                else if (state.length>0 && street.length>0){
                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", street,state];
                }
                else if (city.length>0 && street.length>0){
                    address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", street,city];
                }
                else if (country.length>0){
                    address = country;
                }
                else if (state.length>0){
                    address = state;
                }
                else if (city.length>0){
                    address = city;
                }
            }
            else{
                address = @" ";
            }
        }

        //NSLog(@"address = %@", address);

        NSData  *imgData = (__bridge_transfer NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);

        dataObj.name = Name;
        dataObj.email = Email;
        dataObj.phone = phoneNumber;
        dataObj.imageData = imgData;
        dataObj.address = address;

        [contactArr addObject:dataObj];

    }
    NSLog(@"contacts loaded");
    //NSLog(@"count = %lu", (unsigned long)contactArr.count);
}
else {

    //Go to settings and allow access to use contacts[GlobalFunction removeWaitView];

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the correct frameworks imported:

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
```

Fetch the contacts of AddressBook like this:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate( );
CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople( addressBook );
CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount( addressBook );

for ( int i = 0; i < nPeople; i++ )
{
    ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex( allPeople, i );
    //further code   
}
```

Then populate the UITableView as usual (as per the example you already provided).

Thankfully this framework is being deprecated. The new Contacts API in iOS 9 is gorgeous.

Comment: I need to implement this by taking a ns object class because i need a searchbar too . I just need implementation like in link i gave above. ..  @ Woodstock.